# Running a script on a list of files

Tags: awk, grep

I have a script which obtains a .vcf file, parses that and writes that in a .txt

```
grep -v "#" file.vcf | sed 's/chrM/MT/' | sed 's/chrX/X/' | sed 's/chrY/Y/' | awk '{print $1,$2,$2,$4"/"$5,"+"}' | sed 's/chr//g' > vcf_output.txt
```

I have 27 `.vcf` files on which I want to run this script at the same time and write the output of each `.vcf` in a `.txt` file by the name of that `.vcf`

I found this in google but nothing happens after running that

```
for f in *.vcf; do
    script "$f" > "${f%.*}.txt"
done
```

I adopted that like below

```
for f in *.vcf; do

grep -v "#" | sed 's/chrM/MT/' | sed 's/chrX/X/' | sed 's/chrY/Y/' | awk '{print $1,$2,$2,$4"/"$5,"+"}' | sed 's/chr//g' "$f" > "${f%.*}.txt"
    done
```

I also tried that

```
(base) loan-mac-13:Pre_Treatment fi1d18$ find -type f -name "*.vcf" | xargs grep -v "#" | sed 's/chrM/MT/' | sed 's/chrX/X/' | sed 's/chrY/Y/' | awk '{print $1,$2,$2,$4"/"$5,"+"}' | sed 's/chr//g' "$f" > "${f%.*}.txt"
find: illegal option -- t
usage: find [-H | -L | -P] [-EXdsx] [-f path] path ... [expression]
       find [-H | -L | -P] [-EXdsx] -f path [path ...] [expression]
sed: : No such file or directory
(base) loan-mac-13:Pre_Treatment fi1d18$
```

How I can push this to work for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You converted `script "$f"` in your google output to `grep -v "#"` (i.e. missing the `"$f"`) in your shell loop script and then you're using `"$f"` instead of `{}` and using it in the wrong place in your `xargs` script.

You never need a bunch of seds and greps in a pipleine when you're using awk anyway though. You didn't provide any sample input/output so the following awk script is just a straight translation of your existing pipeline and there's probably a better way to write it, but this one awk script is all you need, no shell loops or anything else:

```
awk '
    FNR == 1 {
        close(out)
        out = FILENAME
        sub(/\.vcf$/,".txt",out)
    }
    !/#/ {
        sub(/chrM/,"MT")
        sub(/chrX/,"X")
        sub(/chrY/,"Y")
        $0 = $1 OFS $2 OFS $2 OFS $4 "/" $5 OFS "+"
        gsub(/chr/,"")
        print > out
    }
' *.vcf
```

If you want to cram it onto fewer lines like you did with your grep+seds+awk pipeline you can just use semicolons everywhere there's a newline you want to get rid of except after each `{`, e.g.:

```
awk 'FNR==1{close(out); out=FILENAME; sub(/\.vcf$/,".txt",out)} !/#/{sub(/chrM/,"MT"); sub(/chrX/,"X"); sub(/chrY/,"Y"); $0=$1 OFS $2 OFS $2 OFS $4 "/" $5 OFS "+"; gsub(/chr/,""); print > out}' *.vcf
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use find and xargs for that.

Find will list all the files.

```
find -type f -name "*.vcf"
```

With xargs we can operate on every file that was found.

```
find -type f -name "*.vcf" | xargs grep -v "#" | sed 's/chrM/MT/' | sed 's/chrX/X/' | sed 's/chrY/Y/' | awk '{print $1,$2,$2,$4"/"$5,"+"}' | sed 's/chr//g' "$f" > "${f%.*}.txt"
```

should do the job?

greetings

Comment: Sorry I got error, I put your code and the error in the post please have a look

Answer (score 0):

Without altering any of your flow, the below should work. Notice that you weren't inputting anything to the first command grep in the pipeline. So nothing was moving.

```
for f in *.vcf; do

< "$f"  grep -v "#" | sed 's/chrM/MT/' | sed 's/chrX/X/' | sed 's/chrY/Y/' | awk '{print $1,$2,$2,$4"/"$5,"+"}' | sed 's/chr//g'  > "${f%.*}.txt"
    done
```

Comment: Sorry says command not found

Comment: I am sure you didn't paste the leading `<`  in your setup, taking it to be something extraneous. Obviously the vcf file cannot be a command and so it gives that error.