# Running a code on a set of files in mac terminal

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I have a script which modifies .txt files

This is my script

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}{split($1,a,"_"); split(a[3],b,"/"); print a[1],a[2],b[1],b[2],$0}' file.txt | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}{split($18,a,";"); split(a[2],b,"="); print b[2],$0}' > out_file.txt
```

I have a bunch of files in a folder

I want to run this script on my files and return each output bythe name of original file

I tried this

```
 > for  i in `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname "*.txt" awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}{split($1,a,"_"); split(a[3],b,"/"); print a[1],a[2],b[1],b[2],$0}'| awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}{split($18,a,";"); split(a[2],b,"="); print b[2],$0}'print > out}' *.txt
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `|'
(base) user112$
```

But nothing happened

Comment: Can't see a trace of your `script` in the code that you tried.

Comment: Sorry I edited my main post please have a look

Comment: It's not "nothing happened"; what happened is that the shell reported you a syntax error. The error is probably that you have an unequal number of single quotes (`'`) and also an unequal number of backticks

Comment: Sorry do you know how to solve that?

Comment: I don't know what `return each output bythe name of original file` means. Please [edit] your question to provide concise, testable sample input and expected output. Piping awk into awk doesn't make any sense btw - unless you're messing with `RS` (which you aren't) you can always easily just do it all in 1 awk script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for i in *.txt; do
    
    awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}{split($1,a,"_"); split(a[3],b,"/"); print a[1],a[2],b[1],b[2],$0}' $i | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}{split($18,a,";"); split(a[2],b,"="); print b[2],$0}' > $i'_1'.txt
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're trying to do?

```
awk '
    BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }
    FNR == 1 {
        close(out)
        out = FILENAME "_1.txt"
    }
    {
        split($1,a,/_/)
        split(a[3],b,"/")
        $0 = a[1] OFS a[2] OFS b[1] OFS b[2] OFS $0
        split($18,a,/;/)
        split(a[2],b,/=/)
        print b[2], $0 > out
   }
' *.txt
```

No shell loops or pipes to multiple commands required, exactly like I showed you in your last question posted under your other name: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/605896/133219. Again, there's probably a better way to do whatever it is you're trying to do but without sample input/output all I can do is copy your script.